# crm 2013 online custom workflow write to text file

Tags: workflow, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am using CRM 2013 Online. I have a requirement to generate a batch file from crm records for our billing system. I was wondering if someone could confirm that a custom workflow on CRM online is able to write to a text file via streamwriter for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can't write directly to text file via streamwriter with CRM Online, because workflows are sandboxed.

The alternative is to create the file in memory and add is at attachment to a record, or send it by email as attachment, or host a Web Service in Azure and store the file there, etc etc.